# How to bind a modified property to a control Windows Universal Apps (XAML/C#)

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I am working on a windows universal app and I'm trying to work out data binding.

I have a listview which has an item template and data template in which a property of a custom class is bound.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Textblock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This works fine an displays the names all instances of my custom class in the ObservableCollection I bind to the listview. I was wondering however if there is some way of modifying what is being bound before it is bound without changing the class itself.

I'm trying to bind a capitalisation of the string property Name so if the name was `Test` I want to bind `TEST` instead. Currently the way I'm doing this is to have a separate property called `NameLabel` which I populate like this

```
NameLabel = Name.ToUpper();
```

However this seems very messy and I was wondering if there's a neater way of doing it without creating a separate property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a converter, that turns the value of a property into a form desired for the view (in your case, a simple capitalisation of the string).

Your converter class might look like this:

```
 public class StringToUpperStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var valueString = value.ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueString))
            {
                return valueString.ToUpper();
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Your xaml might have this defined in the resource section:

```
<converters:StringToUpperStringConverter x:Key="StringToUpperStringConverter" />
```

And your binding would then look like this:

```
<Textblock Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource StringToUpperStringConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Create a StringToUpper.cs File with a StringToUpper Class which inherits form IValueConverter:

```
public class StringToUpper: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var valueString = value.ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueString))
        {
            return valueString.ToUpper();
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // do nothing.
    }
}
```

Add the resource of your created Converter:

```
    ...   
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:StringToUpper"
    ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <converter:StringToUpper x:Key="StringToUpperConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

Add the converter:

```
<Textblock Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource StringToUpperConverter}}"/>
```

[Here](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) is a good Tutorial about Converters in WPF.